# Visualization for "Cutting off a Corner of a 2-meter Square"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Corner of a 2 meter square is cut off to form a regular octagon. Determine the length of the resulting side of the octagon?

Answer is 0.828

I need help visualizing this; if you cut off a corner of a 2m square; then shouldn't all the sides of the octagon be 2m?

Comment: It is all four corners, slice off an isosceles right triangle at each corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question makes sense only if you cut off *all four corners* of the square to make an octagon, as in the diagram.

[image]

To solve the problem, note that if the side of the octagon is $x$ then the side of the square is

$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}x+x+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}x$$

Set that equal to $2$ and solve for $x$.